# List<T> member of POJO Flink type

Tags: apache-flink

I have a type in a Flink job with the following POJO definition

```
public class Allocation {
    private long count;
    private String name;
    private long core;
    private List<Long> ids;

    // constructor, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

This is failing to be collected in an operator, due to `java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Generic types have been disabled in the ExecutionConfig and type java.util.List is treated as a generic type.` - I want to force the POJO serialisation and not fallback to Kryo for performance reasons

I understand I need specify some kind of `TypeInformation` to hint what the serializer should do, however it's unclear to me whether the contained type of the `TypeInformation` can just be the class itself, or I must add all members with their types to this object. And then where do I register this `TypeInformation` object with the system, given that I have several operators into which this type ingresses and egresses (ie via `Collector<Allocation>::collect`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Flink 1.14 onward you can handle this like this:

```java
public class Allocation {
  ...
  @TypeInfo(ListInfoFactory.class)
  private List<Long> ids;
  ...
}

public static class ListInfoFactory<E> extends TypeInfoFactory<List<E>> {
  @Override
  public TypeInformation<List<E>> createTypeInfo(Type t, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> genericParameters) {
    TypeInformation<?> elementType = genericParameters.get("E");
    if (elementType == null) {
      throw new InvalidTypesException("Type extraction is not possible on List (element type unknown).");
    }

    return Types.LIST((TypeInformation<E>) elementType);
  }
}
```

Prior to 1.14 you would have to provide a TypeInfoFactory for the entire Allocation class, rather than for the specific field that has the issue.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Do you have an idea of how a Set could be annotated in the same pattern? As the `TypeInfoFactory` only has one template parameter it's not possible to declare an OUT type different from the IN type, in which case we could just serialise it forward as a list

Comment: Thanks, glad this worked! There's built-in support for Lists and Maps that you can tap into this way, but not for Sets. I'm not sure how to make that work.