provide type information for implementation of Map to Flink
I have the following class:
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Foo extends HashMap<Bar, Baz> {
}

Flink cannot serialize this class without further help or resorting to Kryo, this test fails:
import org.apache.flink.types.PojoTestUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class FooTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
            PojoTestUtils.assertSerializedAsPojoWithoutKryo(Foo.class);
    }
}

I tried the following to  no avail:
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInfoFactory;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
@TypeInfo(Foo.FooTypeInfoFactory.class)
public class Foo extends HashMap<Bar, Baz> {
        public static class FooTypeInfoFactory extends
                TypeInfoFactory<Foo> {
            @Override
            public TypeInformation<Foo> createTypeInfo(Type type, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> map) {
                var type = (TypeInformation<Foo>)
                        Types.MAP(TypeInformation.of(Bar.class), TypeInformation.of(Baz.class));
                return type;
            }
        }
}

But this does not work because
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation<java.util.Map<Bar,Baz>>' to 'org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation<Foo>'

Is there some way to make this idea work? Foo implements Map<Bar, Baz> so it seems to me that I should be able to tell Flink somehow, that it should be serialized like a Map.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/78049074/2000823 I gave an example showing how to do this for lists. Hopefully you can adapt this example to handle maps instead.

I saw that, it’s not quite the same. I’m trying to create type info for the implementation of Map, not for Map itself. This is because, the usages of Foo refer to Foo, not to Map.
